# How can I add transitioning animation in my controller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to add transitioning animation in my controller but I can't do that `transitioningDelegate = self` not working in my code. I didn't solve it can you help me? I use `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController` .
Here my code:

```
    func haliCell() {
    let detailvc = haliCellDetail()
    detailvc.nameForDetail = name
    detailvc.imageDetail = imageDenemeHome
    let top = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: detailvc)
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    top?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last step must be like that in below. I assume that you try to show your navigation controller with transition animation.

```
UIView.transition(with: navigationController, duration: 1.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {

    top?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```